# How to use Caps Lock as Enter in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout, remapping

After extensive search, I've only found guides to remap/swap <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to something like <kbd>Control</kbd>. However, I am trying to make <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> another Enter (to be precise, I want it for one-handed 'Run' in Rstudio).

It seems that the XKB-options only allow very specific commands that can be found by:

```
man 7 xkeyboard-config
```

These options are also the ones that most tweak tools allow. Is there any more powerful option, that allows remapping <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to an arbitrary key, in particular <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or should I give up my search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First You can search for replacements keycodes in your case via following command in terminal:

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep Caps
keycode  66 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock

$ xmodmap -pke | grep Enter
keycode 104 = KP_Enter NoSymbol KP_Enter
```

You can get all keycodes according to keys by command `xmodmap -pke`.

So, **Run following command (to get Caps-Lock Work as Enter Key)**:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = KP_Enter"
```

(Then you can set/assign suitable key to keycode by command `xmodmap -e`)

Comment: You can also use Tweak toll.

Comment: Thanks so much! However, the Caps Lock function still worked, which means my case changed each time I used it as Enter. Disabling Caps Lock in (Gnome) Tweak Tool, then running your command worked, however, so that's great. 

Also, I assume this resets when I reboot? Maybe I could add this command to startup?

Comment: Yes it is reset after reboot and you can add this command to startup.

Comment: @KeesMulder To remove caps lock functionality delete the associated line under modifier mappings, e.g.  `modifier_map Lock   { Caps_Lock };` in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` where the key mappings are stored.